# How can I combine these SQL queries to be more efficient for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, insert

I have the following queries that I would like to possibly combine into one or two larger queries:

```
SELECT user, password, email FROM users WHERE user = 'njp316' LIMIT 1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO collectors_users (username, password, email, dateadded, subscribed)
VALUES (user, password, email, NOW(), 'Y');
```

This one will pull back multiple rows, so it will need to loop:

```
SELECT barcode FROM collections WHERE user = user;

INSERT IGNORE INTO collections_collections (username, barcode)
VALUES (user, barcode);
```

Obviously I'm not advanced with SQL so just looking for some help. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you'd have to write a store procedure. I don't think you can do that another way, but I'll wait for some real experts to chime in.

Comment: what is the client code feeding this?  I.e. Java,c++,etc

Comment: The client code will be PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something... this is pretty simple:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO collectors_users
(username, password, email, dateadded, subscribed)
SELECT user, password, email, NOW(), 'Y'
FROM users 
WHERE user = 'njp316' 
LIMIT 1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO collections_collections 
(username, barcode)
SELECT user, barcode 
FROM collections 
WHERE user = user;
```

Comment: WHERE user = user; - I was hoping to get the username somehow from the first query here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect.

```
INSERT INTO collectors_users (username, password, email, dateadded, subscribed)
SELECT user, password, email, NOW(), 'Y' FROM users WHERE user='njp316' LIMIT 1;
```

It uses the SELECT as the source of the data to pour into the INSERT.  Note that order of columns matters.

Comment: Won't that only insert a single record though?

Comment: Yes, only one record will be inserted.  Drop the `LIMIT` if you want to not limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO collectors_users (username, `password`, email, dateadded, subscribed) 
SELECT `user`, `password`, email, NOW(), 'Y' 
FROM users WHERE `user` = 'njp316' LIMIT 1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO collections_collections (username, barcode) 
SELECT `user`,barcode 
FROM collections WHERE `user` = 'njp316';
```